# How do I suggest tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tags, faq

I understand tags can have synonyms, for example [rpg] can be a synonym of [role-playing-games]. How can I suggest new synonyms to existing tags?

Comment: What are the requirements? Kind of an important point.

Comment: I'm not sure if Macha's question is the same as mine, but in order to suggest a tag synonym, do you have to have access to moderation tools? What level of rep does this become accessible?

Comment: No idea. 1000 reputation, maybe? The answer is probably buried in meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit that tag's page and click on the info tab. If your suggestion has already been made, upvote it.

You can also see a [list of pending and active tag synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Once a suggestion reaches a score of 3, it is automatically accepted.

Answer (score 2):

As of August 2, 2010, users require 1000 reputation in order to suggest tag synonyms.

Comment: I have 1000+ reputation and can suggest synonyms.

Comment: Do you have access to the other moderation tools?

Comment: Nope... not yet.

Comment: Confirmed at 1000 rep.  Edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: The current requirement seems to be "more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag [for which you'd like to request a synonym]".